# Program has stopped working Event Name: CLR20r3

Tags: signature

When I  run my program in other computers except mine,it shows the following error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: testMyproject.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 53ab6aaa
  Problem Signature 04: System.Windows.Forms
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.33440
  Problem Signature 06: 52004310
  Problem Signature 07: c2a
  Problem Signature 08: 11
  Problem Signature 09: PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 8096
  Additional Information 2: 809605f83e81c70b2a1fc717aae361c3
  Additional Information 3: ab09
  Additional Information 4: ab09016fe7e82c5c86ab5527a84309dd

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: I also encounter this kind of problem .I am about to post a question like this but i found this one already but unfortunately, No one is still answering this one. :(

Answer (score 1):

If the application has no chance to get debug information, it will not create more details about the crash instead of the data above in your post. If you want to know what could be the reason in detail, [Windows event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) has a chance to give it.
German: [Ereignisprotokoll](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

You can scroll to the application which causes the fault and see some more details.
[image: Event viewer sample]

Additional, if it is possible, you can install [WinDbg or any other debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) tool for free on the computer. This debugger can catch the error with additional details.

*** update ***

Check out dependencies with [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). The explained error ´CLR20r3 Locale ID:    1033` just tells, that no exception information is available. That can occur if not all needed dependencies are on computer.

[image]

Comment: Event viewer is not capturing any details about application.

Comment: Have you checked all DLL´s with correct CPU architecture? Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've have the same problem. Try to copy, with your exe file, all the others referenced assembly (dll) on the deployment machine or in the installation kit.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the SAP Crystal Reports Runtime engine and it will start working. I have done the same thing and my application start working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried multiple options didnot worked,
So finally recreated VM and now working but the issue is application stops working after reboot, So decided not to reboot system till I find some good solution.